# Extract version from string using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I could not seem to figure out the proper regex (java style) to extract just the *version* part for these string

```
EXPECTATION
spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar  -> 4.2.5
rumi-1.js                     -> 1
BouncyCastle-Net-12-1.dll     -> 12-1
```

With the following java regex I keep getting a period at the end of line

```
\\b\\d[\\d|\\.|\\-]*\\b
```

Anyone can suggest a better regex?

```
 FAULTY_RESULT
 spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar  -> 4.2.5.
 rumi-1.js                     -> 1.
 BouncyCastle-Net-12-1.dll     -> 12-1.
```

Comment: So what you want is...? Some digits, followed by one non-digit, repeated, but ending in a digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digit(s), followed by zero or more lots of a dot/dash and digit(s), not preceded by a word character:

```
(?<!\w)\d+([.-]\d+)*
```

In java, it can be done in one line:

```
String version = packageName.replaceAll(".*?((?<!\\w)\\d+([.-]\\d+)*).*", "$1");
```

Here, the target term is captured while the regex matches the entire input and the replacement term returns the target (via the captured group).

Comment: Sir, you're a genius! Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @YCF_L Yes. Didn't re-thumb it in correctly. Fixed now.

Comment: @ycf I have edited the regex accordingly

Comment: mmm, i'm sorry for being annoying but it return `spring1-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar` i try this `String version = "spring1-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar".replaceAll(".*?((?!\\w)\\d+([.-]\\d+)*).*", "$1");` maybe i don't use it correctly you fan guide me

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can get this expression better, but this is my first attempt. Note. you need to scape this expression.

```
(\d+(\.?|-?|\d)+\d|\d)
```

regards.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
\b\d[\d|.|\-]*\d\b
```

The doubling of the back-slashes goes into the `String` constant only:

```
"\\b\\d[\\d|.|\\-]+*\\d\\b"
```

However this will not match a single digit version...

Comment: You haven't explained why this regex would solve the problem

Comment: Note that this would match things like `3-----4` or `3.-.-4`

Comment: As does the original, too.